# Is there a way to remove GoPro fisheye using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fisheye, gopro

It seems possible to compensate the fisheye distortion using ffmpeg thanks to the [lenscorrection](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lenscorrection) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "lenscorrection=cx=0.5:cy=0.5:k1=-.25:k2=-.25" out.mp4
```

What values for `k1` and `k2`, particularly for a gopro?
Is there a way to compute them?

Comment: Duplicate over in video:  http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12667/linux-command-line-option-to-do-video-lens-correction

Comment: @abernier I think providing an example **input** image (video grab) would speed up getting some Answers.

Answer (score 20):

I don't think there's a generic one setting(s) to cover all GoPro models & lenses. Factor in also that people can use some customised/replacement lenses.

I was hoping for an example image featuring **what you have to work with**, but never mind...
 
Hope the below is useful to you in some way

Check this link for [**`GoPro Hero 3 settings`**](https://gopro.com/support/articles/hero3-field-of-view-fov-information) (applies to other models). To get a rough idea of best `k1` and `k2` values, you should find the nearest **aspect ratio** to your image resolution then...

Divide the `H. FOV deg` with the `V. FOV deg` and multiply result with `Diag. FOV deg`.

Example: *where picture size is 1920 x 1080* : This makes it 16:9 widescreen.

> GoPro 3 setting:  16 x 9 Widescreen :: `H fov` = 69.5 || `V fov` = 118.2 ||    `Diag` = 133.6

So `118.2 / 69.5 * 133.6 = 227.216 etc`

for `k1` the result is now integer  `227` (drop the decimal points).

for `k2` the value `0.022` seems universal (all test images), so you can try `k2=-.022`.

for `cx` and `cy` keep them as : `cx=0.5:cy=0.5:`.

Example:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "lenscorrection=cx=0.5:cy=0.5:k1=-0.227:k2=-0.022" out.mp4`

Result : (original image found via [Google images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=648&q=go+pro+fisheye&oq=go+pro+fisheye&gs_l=img.3..0i10i30k1j0i10i24k1l2.2135.6301.0.6638.14.14.0.0.0.0.233.1528.4j8j1.13.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.13.1519...0j0i10k1.U346YgWEqIs#imgrc=pKeJUlbQodTb8M%3A) of a GoPro Hero-2 video).

[image]

Comment: Excellent! You've just won the bounty ;) However, can you explain the k2 value a bit more? Why it is "universal" ? Thanks again

Comment: @abernier Thanks. About `k2` it's not so much that it's universal but just that it works for that type of fish-eye lens. My test pictures all had an "image inside a circle" type of look (with black edges). It may not be best for panoramic lens (distorted image but fils screen without black edges). I'm off on a mission right now, but will update with extra info/examples later tonight.

Answer (score 6):

For GoPro Hero 5 and 6:

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
    -vf 'lenscorrection=k2=0.006:k1=-0.18' \
    output.mp4
```

[source](https://sourceforge.net/p/lensfun/mailman/lensfun-users/thread/B51B8A2A-B512-4200-B3F3-41318EF7AE88%40gmail.com/#msg36614619)

Answer (score 4):

FFmpeg has a [`lenscorrection`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lenscorrection) filter that can be used to correct radial distortion in videos. That said, without more context - such as the model and settings of your camera - it would be hard to provide more information. I suspect it would require a bit of trial-and-error anyway.

PS: Have you tried running the camera's software under [WINE](http://winehq.com)? Some versions of it apparently have this kind of correction filter predefined and easily accessible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for ffmpeg parameters for lenscorrection (or other opensource, without using 3rd party software).

Comment: yep, thx for the answer but specific values for `k1` and `k2` would be awesome for gopro

Answer (score 4):

I wrote [a post](https://www.danielplayfaircal.com/blogging/ffmpeg/lensfun/v360/lenscorrection/fisheye/dodgeball/2020/03/24/correcting-lens-distortion-with-ffmpeg.html) about various methods for correcting distortion using ffmpeg - I think the `lensfun` or `v360` filters are better options than the lenscorrection filter.

That said, in theory you should be able to calculate values for k1 and k2 using OpenCV- [calibrateCamera](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d) function. You would want to use the flags `CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT` (along with coordinates to fix the principal point at the center of the image as lenscorrection assumes), `CALIB_FIX_K3` (since lenscorrection does not use `k3`), and `CALIB_FIX_S1_S2_S3_S4` (since lenscorrection does not consider tangential distortion). There is example code available that you can simply modify to do this.

However when I tried, I got stuck because I couldn't find a way to fix the focal length in OpenCV, but in lenscorrection the focal length is hard coded to half of the image diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

For GoPro 3+, 16:9 with FOV Wide

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "lenscorrection=0.5:0.5:-0.335:0.097" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fix fisheye using ffmpeg's `lenscorrection`, but the result will look bad on edges.

[image: Image of how it looks on edges]